# C# SubItems Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview

I'm a student learning C#, with previous experiences with VB. I'm trying to use a list view to display three pieces of information in three separate columns. The Item is a decimal (Object = 3.50m), and the subItems are the quantity and a price. I have managed to get the first two columns showing the data with:-

```
var item = lsvstarter.Items.Add(cmbStarter.Text);
item.SubItems.Add(cmbStrQuantity.Text);
```

The third column should show the worth of the item multiplied by the quantity, so it would be

```
1st Column "3.50"
2nd Column "3"
3rd Column (3.50 * 3) "10.5"
```

But the method I used for the first subitem will not work for the variable that should be displayed by the third column. This being

```
item.SubItems.Add(Startertotal);
```

The ListView includes 3 columns. I had this program working on VB since the scenario is the same but using translators didn't work successfully. All of the objects in the Design view are the same.

Also the calculation for the "Startertotal" variable has already been calculated in a loop beforehand. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and the fix?

Comment: Why won't that work? Can you elaborate?

Comment: My guess you forgot to add 3d column to `ListView` in form designer.

Comment: It doesn't accept the variable with the second SubItem, I don't know why as it allows another bit of data just above it. Perhaps how I calculated it previously may be wrong. I did it with this

            else if ((cmbStarter.SelectedIndex == 3))
            {
                Startertotal = (SpicyFiloSamosas * decimal.Parse(cmbStrQuantity.Text));
            }

Comment: Can you be more specific about *what* isn't working? Does it throw an exception? Display the wrong value?

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN: SubItems.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/e7x34tef%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes either a string or a `SubItem` as its first parameter.

So you need to change the numeric value to a string in one way or another:

```
item.SubItems.Add(Startertotal + " ");
item.SubItems.Add(Startertotal + "");
item.SubItems.Add(Startertotal.ToString());    
item.SubItems.Add(Startertotal.ToString("###0,00"));
item.SubItems.Add(String.Format("Sum: {0} ", Startertotal));
```

or whatever formatting you want..